# Teamcity - automatic weekly incrementation of build number

Tags: build, version, teamcity, versioning

has anybody a hint how it is possible to increment a second part of the number below ("249") on weekly basis? TeamCity is able to increase after every build the number of the build counter, so far so good.

1.0.***249***.%build.counter%

Additionally I need to increase the 249 on weekly basis automatically.
eg.: 249 > 250; 250 > 251; 101 > 102; 41 > 42;...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this by programatically re-defining the `build.number` in a PowerShell build step.

1. Add a PowerShell build step as the first step in your configuration.
2. Set the following parameters in that build step:

   - `Script`: *Source Code*
   - `Script execution mode`: *Execute .ps1 script with "File" argument*
   - `Script source`:

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.$([Math]::Floor([DateTime]::Now.DayOfYear/7)).%build.counter%']"
```

All subsequent build steps should be able to use the new `build.number` value.

The `$([Math]::Floor([DateTime]::Now.DayOfYear/7))` is the magic; it produces the current week of the year. You'll need to massage this a little bit to conform to your existing numbering.

**A note about reuse:** You'll want to parameterize the `1.0` major/minor value in order to reuse this step across multiple projects. I'd define a parameter, `%major.minor%`, and set its value to 1.0 (or whatever.) The PowerShell script would then be this:

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '%major.minor%.$([Math]::Floor([DateTime]::Now.DayOfYear/7)).%build.counter%']"
```

**Edit:** Switched to a simpler `Write-Host` implementation as mentioned by Jacob.

Comment: I expected this to work as well, but could not make it work.  I decided to look over the source of the [SemVer Metarunner](https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack/blob/master/semver-buildnumber/MRPP_SemVer_BuildNumber.xml) and noticed they use a different syntax:

`Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$BuildNumber']"`

I switched to that format and it worked, so it may vary by TeamCity version.  Also note that setting the buildNumber this does not seem to work with the AssemblyInfo, because it does its thing very early in the build.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to get that created versionnumber in the assemblies. Right now it adds the buildnumber using an assemblyinfopatcher step and in my buildsteps I update the versionnumber using the created number. But as you mentioned that step runs after the assemblyinfopatcher step. Did you manage to work around this issue?

Comment: Documentation for that clever "talk back to TC" feature is here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a way to customize the build number in TeamCity I happened to stumble upon this question.  The provided answer by @john-hoerr worked perfectly (thanks for that).

I have taken John's answer and modified it for my needs.  Here is a powershell script that will update the build number using the provided build number format from the general tab of the build configuration settings, a date format (of any nature) and the build counter from TeamCity:

```
# The build number format is YYDDD.BB 
# YY is the last two digits of the year
# DDD is the day number in the year (1-365)
# BB is the build number of the day for this build type (1-N)

# Get the build number from TeamCity. This will contain whatever is placed 
# into the build number portion of the build definition
$TeamCityBuildNumber = "%build.number%"

# Get the build counter from TeamCity and ensure it's in the format 00 (for sorting).  
# Assumption: there are less than 100 builds a day for this build definition.
$TeamCityBuildCounter = "%build.counter%".PadLeft(2, "0")

# The build number really just contains the date portion of the whole build number string.  I am tweaking it to also contain a branch name but have removed this from my example code for simplicity purposes.
$BuildNumber = ([string]::Concat(([DateTime]::Now.Date.Year - 2000),([DateTime]::Now.DayOfYear)))

# Write the build number to the host, effectively altering the build number 
# within the process space of the build.
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$TeamCityBuildNumber.$BuildNumber.$TeamCityBuildCounter']"
```

Ideally the build counter resets to 0 at midnight so that the first build of the day receives a build counter value of 1.

Comment: how do you reset build counter to 1 nightly?